# How to execute SQL scripts using azure databricks

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I have one SQL scripts file
In that file there is some sql query
I want to upload it on dbfs and read it from azure databricks and execute querys from the script on azure databricks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Databricks does not directly support the execution of .sql files. However you could just read them into a string and execute them.

```
with open("/dbfs/path/to/query.sql") as queryFile:
   queryText = queryFile.read()
results = spark.sql(queryText)
```